# PhantomJS bridge for NodeJS: paperSize do not work correctly

Tags: node.js, phantomjs

I use PhantomJS bridge for NodeJS.
I want to render PDF file with 595x842 px size.

```
var phantom = require('phantom');
phantom.create(function(ph) {
    ph.createPage(function(page) {
        page.set('paperSize', {width: '595px', height: '842px', border: '0px' });
        page.open("http://localhost:3000", function(status) {
            if (status !== 'success') {
                console.log('Unable to access the network!');
            } else {
                page.render('filename.pdf');
            }
            ph.exit();
        });
    });
});
```

But, by the end I get 235x331px PDF file. I can't understand why. Maybe someone can help and explain me how can I render necessary file size ?

Comment: Try using: page.paperSize = {width: '595px', height: '842px', border: '0px' };

Comment: It didn't help. Your syntax approach for PhantomJS, but not for NodeJs module "PhantomJS bridge for NodeJS".

Comment: https://github.com/sgentle/phantomjs-node it is stated that set/get cannot be called directly. This might work for you: ph.page.set('paperSize', {width: '595px', height: '842px', border: '0px' });

Comment: I haven't any errors in my code. Just generated file has incorrect sizes. I want to understand why.

Comment: Did you get why this wasn't working? I having the same issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reviewing the [repo tutorial](https://github.com/sgentle/phantomjs-node) I found this:

> Properties can't be get/set directly, instead use page.get('version',
>   callback) or page.set('viewportSize', {width:640,height:480}), etc.
>   Nested objects can be accessed by including dots in keys, such as
>   page.set('settings.loadImages', false)

So I tried the following code:

```
var phantom = require('phantom');

phantom.create(function(ph) {

    ph.createPage(function(page) {

        page.set('viewportSize', { width : 595, height : 842});
        page.open("http://localhost:3000", function(status) {
            if (status !== 'success') {
                console.log('Unable to access the network!');
            } else {
                page.render('filename.pdf');
            }
            ph.exit();

        });
    });
});
```

Hope this works for you, like it did for me.